# Laravel: View [Site.home.index] not found

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, file-not-found, directadmin

I was getting this error when upload my source from local to server: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYRCo.png)

Can anyone help me fix this problem...

```php
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 140:
View [Site.home.index] not found.


in FileViewFinder.php line 140
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('Site.home.index', array('/home/diamondp/domains/diamondpalace.vn/public_html/resources/views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 77
at FileViewFinder->find('Site.home.index') in Factory.php line 145
at Factory->make('Site.home.index', array('title' => 'Nhà hàng Diamone Palace', 'about' => object(About), 'hoatdong' => object(Collection), 'address' => 'Lô 2+3 A4.3 đường Trần Thị Lý, Khu Đảo Xanh - TP Đà Nẵng.', 'lat' => '16.0658096', 'lng' => '108.2200476', 'lienhe' => object(stdClass), 'uudai' => object(Collection), 'intro' => object(Collection)), array()) in helpers.php line 592
at view('Site.home.index', array('title' => 'Nhà hàng Diamone Palace', 'about' => object(About), 'hoatdong' => object(Collection), 'address' => 'Lô 2+3 A4.3 đường Trần Thị Lý, Khu Đảo Xanh - TP Đà Nẵng.', 'lat' => '16.0658096', 'lng' => '108.2200476', 'lienhe' => object(stdClass), 'uudai' => object(Collection), 'intro' => object(Collection))) in HomeController.php line 46
at HomeController->index()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(HomeController), 'index'), array()) in Controller.php line 246
at Controller->callAction('index', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(HomeController), object(Route), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 41
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
```

Comment: What is your controller code?

Comment: Is the file you are pointing to in following path
resources/views/Site/home/index.blade.php ?